# Checking CakePHP ACL permissions by URL

Tags: php, cakephp, permissions, cakephp-2.0, acl

I'm using the CakePHP ACL CRUD system in my webapplications and i'm trying to generate some menu's based on the permissions for the user currently logged in.

I'm facing a problem which is not documented in the CakePHP manual (at least I couldn't find it). I would like to check the permissions based on the following URL-format:

```
$url = '/admin/users/add';
$this->Acl->check(array('User' => array('id' => 2)), $url);
```

I've tried to parse the URL to a array-format with Router::parse() but check() is not able to handle this format.

The second parameter of Acl->check() expects a "Array with 'model' and 'foreign_key', model object, or string value"..

What is the best way to transform my $url to a format that checks() accepts?

Comment: Store the url in session data ..give it a try

Comment: Unless you have the URL itself stored as an access control object (ACO) in your database, I think you're using the ACL incorrectly. I suggest reading and re-reading the [ACL section](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/acl-component) of Cake's manual as this is probably the hardest section to fully understand.

Answer (score 0):

urls map to controllers and actions, so use ActionsAuthorize for this